# How to use a variable from one class in another to show up on my next storyboard scene

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I guess this has been asked before but I can't find something that I can use to answer my question and get this to work. So, here's what I have. In once class, I have the following:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *totalAmountLabel;
```

and I've also setup the following the score the total in:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *finalTotal;
```

So I've set my amount to that String in one class, but how exactly do I get at it in another class? I assume I import my class, but once I've done that, what do I type to get at this variable? How would I declare an instance of my class to get at this variable, and even then, would I have access to it? Or do I go via the getters and setters that are done for me - if so how do I know what they're called?

I hope that makes sense, thanks in advance so your help.

Comment: How are your scenes interconnected in storyboard? Is there a segue in between?

Comment: There are segues in between, yes.

Comment: Then the answer from @dasblinkenlight should solve your problem. Let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **NsUser default**

**set you object with your keyword**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"Ajay" forKey:@"name"];
```

**than get that object any where in you project**

```
 NSString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: -1 This is by far the worst misuse of the `NSUserDefaults` class that I have seen. The class is designed for an entirely different purpose; using it for data transfer is a serious hack.

Answer (score 5):

> I assume I import my class, but once I've done that, what do I type to get at this variable?

Unfortunately, it is not that simple: you need an object instance in order to set its instance variables. It does not matter if you go through properties or not, you need an instance either way.

The way you get that instance differs depending on how your classes interact. Since you are using ARC and `IBOutlet`s, I am assuming that the `totalAmountLabel` is located in a view controller that you open using a segue. In this case, you need to import the destination controller's header in the starting controller's .m file, and add this code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"goToMyNextController"]) {
    // Change the ID to match the one that you are using ^^^^^^^^^
    MyNextViewController *nvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    [nvc.totalAmountLabel setTitle:finalTotal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```